# Integral Identity

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, integral-equations

A question from a multivariable calculus exam: I have tried lots of methods like integrating the RHS by parts. Any help would be appreciated.

> Find $w(y)$ such that the identity 
>   $$
> \intop_{-1}^{1} \intop_{0}^{x}f(y)dydx=\intop_{0}^{1}w(y)[f(y)-f(-y)]dy
> $$
>   holds for every integrable function $f:[-1,1]\mapsto\mathbb{R}.$

Thanks for the suggestions, does this look right:

Answer:

LHS =

$$
\intop_{-1}^{1}\intop_{0}^{x}f(y)dydx=\intop_{-1}^{0}\intop_{y}^{-1}f(y)dxdy+\intop_{0}^{1}\intop_{y}^{1}f(y)dydx
$$

$$
=\intop_{-1}^{0}f(y)(-1-y)dy+\intop_{0}^{1}f(y)(1-y)dy
$$

integral w.r.t. $x$ is just constant

$$
=\intop_{0}^{1}f(y)(1+y)dy+\intop_{0}^{1}f(y)(1-y)dy
$$

$$
=\intop_{0}^{1}f(-z)(1-z)(-dz)+\intop_{0}^{1}f(y)(1-y)dy\text{ making the substitution $z=-y$}
$$

$$
=-\intop_{0}^{1}f(-y)(1-y)(dy)+\intop_{0}^{1}f(y)(1-y)dy\
$$

since z is dummy variable

$$
=\intop_{0}^{1}(1-y)[f(y)\mathbf{-}f(-y)]dy
$$

So,

$$
w(y)=(1-y)
$$

Comment: Looks like a change in the order of integration will do wonders.

Comment: Have you looked at changing the order of integration?